ConnectionRefusedError after repartitioning a spark dataframe
My spark dataframe has 12 partitions (NYC trip records data for yellow ones for 2022). I'm trying to repartition my spark dataframe to level the size of its partitions.
taxi_df = taxi_df.repartition(10)

But as soon as I repartition it, running taxi_df.show() results in the following error:
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
   178 try:
--> 179     return f(*a, **kw)
   180 except Py4JJavaError as e:

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
   325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
   327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
   328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
   329 else:

<class 'str'>: (<class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 taxi_df.show()

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:945, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
   885 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
   886     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
   887 
   888     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
  (...)
   943     name | Bob
   944     """
--> 945     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:963, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
   957     raise PySparkTypeError(
   958         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
   959         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
   960     )
   962 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 963     return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
   964 else:
   965     try:

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
  1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
  1317     self.command_header +\
  1318     args_command +\
  1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
  1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
  1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
  1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:181, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
   179     return f(*a, **kw)
   180 except Py4JJavaError as e:
--> 181     converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
   182     if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
   183         # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
   184         # JVM exception message.
   185         raise converted from None

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:143, in convert_exception(e)
   141 elif is_instance_of(gw, e, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"):
   142     return IllegalArgumentException(origin=e)
--> 143 elif is_instance_of(gw, e, "java.lang.ArithmeticException"):
   144     return ArithmeticException(origin=e)
   145 elif is_instance_of(gw, e, "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"):

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:464, in is_instance_of(gateway, java_object, java_class)
   460 else:
   461     raise Py4JError(
   462         "java_class must be a string, a JavaClass, or a JavaObject")
--> 464 return gateway.jvm.py4j.reflection.TypeUtil.isInstanceOf(
   465     param, java_object)

File ~\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1664, in JavaPackage.__getattr__(self, name)
  1661     return JavaClass(
  1662         answer[proto.CLASS_FQN_START:], self._gateway_client)
  1663 else:
-> 1664     raise Py4JError("{0} does not exist in the JVM".format(new_fqn))

Py4JError: py4j.reflection does not exist in the JVM

The following part of the error is just printed (not thrown as an exception).
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60537)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 295, in handle
    poll(accum_updates)
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 267, in poll
    if self.rfile in r and func():
                           ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 271, in accum_updates
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 594, in read_int
    length = stream.read(4)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: <exception str() failed>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\clientserver.py", line 511, in send_command
    answer = smart_decode(self.stream.readline()[:-1])
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jatin\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving

